# Converting Excel Table to Geodatabase with Repeating Numbers Results in all Zeroes

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, esri-geodatabase

I'm trying to convert an Excel file to a DBF file. I understand how to do it correctly using the Table to Table tool. However I am having an issue where a column of repeating numbers (labeled ZoneNum) are converted into nothing but zeroes. There doesn't seem to be any other issues with the other columns such as street names, ID number, work done, etc. I believe it has to do with the repeating numbers. For example 16 streets might be under ZoneNum 1 so their attribute would be 1. The next 7 streets might be under ZoneNum 3. I've tried to store the number as text instead but then nothing showed up. I've formatted each column as numbers or text. I've tried converting to a csv file instead to then convert to DBF file with no results. Please help!

Here's 3 sample lines from my file (minus the linebreaks):

```
104,14,Yosemite Drive,Everglade Circle,South End,Cape Seal

105,14,Zion Avenue,Jefferson Street,Carlsbad Street,Slurry Seal

106,17,Aberdeen Drive,Venice Avenue,West End,"1.5"" Edge Grind & Overlay"
```

Comment: What are the names of the rest of the headers (not just ZoneNum)? ArcGIS is very picky with field names and even one bad header can cause problems with the entire import process.

Comment: Based on your tags, it looks like you're using ArcGIS 10.0.  However, 10.2 has a new [Excel to Table tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Excel_To_Table/001200000055000000/) which might work too.

Comment: Conor, Thanks for the help. I overlooked a space preceding ZoneNum. I can't believe I missed that.
Fezter, Thanks for that info. I hope we're due for an upgrade soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I accidentally stumbled upon the issue. The issue was that there was a space preceding ZoneNum. Instead of **"ZoneNum"** it was **" ZoneNum"**. It didn't show up in Excel because of how Excel displays text and it disappeared whenever I tried looking at the created dbf file. It threw no warnings or errors. If it wasn't for Conor asking for the exact header text (I tried copying it from the created csv file just to be exact), I would have completely missed the issue. I feel like an idiot for missing it in the first place. Hopefully someone else finds this information useful. Double check for spaces!